# How to avoid SIG_PIPE crashing in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, sigpipe

I have been facing the SIGPIPE crashing frequently, I know its because of connection problem, one of my socket is trying to write after lost connection, but problem is I don't have here control over the socket descriptors (Got tcp class as .a), to set signal() like IGNORE or NO_SIGPIPE. So any way to igone using Xcode. Any suggestion is really helpful to me.

thanks

Comment: Did you try to close it?

Comment: @Larme some of my .a's are accessing net, I don't have access to it. That's why I am looking for Xcode help :)

Comment: Try to catch it with `@try { ... } @catch(NSException *ex) { ... }`

Comment: did you try ignoring the SIGPIPE with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't have socket descriptors I have tried with Signals it seems working.